# Is there is any way to Indent XML without Using loadXML() in Vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, indentation

Am developing a application for a older windows device. I need to Indent XML without using `loadXML()` function. Because in `loadXML()` I get an exception `Out of Memory`, when it load entire XML.

So I don't want to use that function. Is there is any other way to Indent XML? in Vb.net.

Comment: Use XmlReader and XmlWriter.  You will have to set the settings for XmlWriter to indent.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng Done using XMLWriter